# Managed Server State Integer Value Reference

Tags: weblogic

I'm using a JMX agent to inspect the state of managed servers in a weblogic domain. The only value I can extract with this agent is the StateVal, which is the integer value of the managed servers state. I can't seem to find a complete reference of the integer values of server states. Can anyone point me to a reference, or explain why this isn't a simple request? For instance, here is what I am looking for...

```
State      Value
----------------
SHUTDOWN    ?
STARTING    ?
RUNNING     2
FAILED      ?
...
```

I'm working with version 12.1.

Comment: Did you solved your problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the values you are looking for :

```
SHUTDOWN = 0;
STARTING = 1;
RUNNING = 2;
STANDBY = 3;
SUSPENDING = 4;
FORCE_SUSPENDING = 5;
RESUMING = 6;
SHUTTING_DOWN = 7;
FAILED = 8;
UNKNOWN = 9;
SHUTDOWN_PENDING = 10;
SHUTDOWN_IN_PROCESS = 11;
FAILED_RESTARTING = 12;
ACTIVATE_LATER = 13;
FAILED_NOT_RESTARTABLE = 14;
FAILED_MIGRATABLE = 15;
DISCOVERED = 16;
ADMIN = 17;
FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN = 18;
```

I didn't find it in the weblogic documentation but finally I found the answer on the [Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2200353)

It's for weblogic 11G but I guess the same values are used for weblogic 12C.